# dynamically change button text aria-label not working by switch up/down key

Tags: javascript, html

When I dynamically change button text which is a inline div, the screen reader cannot read aria-label which I add to button. I  switch up/down key on keyboard to focus the each Label. How should I do to make screen reader read aria-label context.
My code is blew,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>
        Create custom shape button
    </title>
</head>
<body>  
    <p>
        <input name="name" class="b_input" id="b_input" value="butterfly"></input>
        <button class="b_create_text" onclick="Func()" width="100px" aria-label="Search for butterfly">click me</button>
    </p>
    <button class="b_button">
        <div class="b_button_label">@("show me more information")</div>
    </button>
    <script>
        function Func() {
            let dir="ltr";
            let inputB = document.getElementById("b_input");
            let inputText = inputB.value;
            let searchDescription = "Search for " + inputText;

            var sideBarLabelNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("b_button_label");
            if (sideBarLabelNodes.length == 1) {
                sideBarLabelNodes[0].textContent = searchDescription;
            }

            let el = document.getElementsByClassName('b_button');
            if(el.length == 1) {
                if(!!searchDescription) {
                    el[0].setAttribute("aria-label", searchDescription);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a screen reader reread if the aria-label changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586961/making-a-screen-reader-reread-if-the-aria-label-changes)